# Why does this ContourPlot3D not give the result I expect?

Tags: plotting

```
ContourPlot3D[(mod[x, 10]-5)^2 + y ^2+z ^2 ==1, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20}]
```

shows blank

[image]
rather than the array of balls I expect. Why?

Comment: It does [QUOTE=David;591115] . Thanks. How then is mod being interpreted?

Comment: It's not being interpreted at all. `mod[x, 10]` evaluates to `mod[x, 10]` because `mod` is undefined. Therefore, `ContourPlot[ mod[x, 10] etc.]` evaluates to itself because the function is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. Can I get OPTION STRICT? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ContourPlot3D[(Mod[x, 10] - 5)^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1,
 {x, -20, 20},
 {y, -20, 20},
 {z, -20, 20}]
```

[image]